# Как ограничить ввод только для чисел в Android Chrome с 'type="tel"'?

Tags: javascript, android

Есть проблема, onkeypress (да и onkeydown) не блокирует в андройде ввод дополнительных символов вроде тире, решетки и т.д.

```
_onKeyPress(event) {
    if (this.props.numbersOnly) {
        const key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.which);
        const regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: используйте `type=number`.  Кнопки увеличения/уменьшения можно `css`-ом убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте эту клавиатуру:

[image: Виртуальная цифровая клавиатура]

[Виртуальная цифровая клавиатура](https://pedro404.wordpress.com/2018/03/07/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/)

```js
var Q;
Q = {};
Q.timeInterval;
Q.flag = 0;

function timeIntervaStart() {
  if (Q.flag === 0) {
    Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
      Clear();
      timeIntervaStart();
      Q.flag = 1;
    }, 300);
  } else if (Q.flag === 1) {
    Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
      Clear();
      Q.flag = 2;
      timeIntervaStart();
    }, 150);
  } else {
    Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
      Clear();
      timeIntervaStart();
    }, 50);
  }
}

window.onmousedown = function() {
  var elem = window.event.srcElement;
  if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
    if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
      timeIntervaStart();
    }
  }
};

window.onmouseup = function() {
  var elem = window.event.srcElement;
  if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
    if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
      clearTimeout(Q.timeInterval);
      Q.flag = 0;
    }
  }
};

window.onclick = function() {
  var elem = window.event.srcElement;
  if (elem.parentNode.id === 'klava') {
    if (elem.innerHTML === '←') {
      Clear();
    } else {
      document.getElementById('input_data').value += elem.innerHTML;
    }
  }
};

function Clear() {
  var str = document.getElementById('input_data').value;
  document.getElementById('input_data').value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

#klava {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #edeef0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#klava button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#klava .back-sp {
  background-color: #4286f5;
  color: #fff;
}

#input_data {
  background-color: #ffffeb;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#klava button,
#input_data {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#klava button:active {
  background-color: #FFB74D;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_data" type="text" onfocus="this.blur();">
<div id="klava">
  <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br>
  <button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br>
  <button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br>
  <button>00</button><button>0</button><button class="back-sp">←</button><br>
</div>
```